# Why is anaconda navigator 1.9.6 opening really slow?

Tags: python, anaconda

When trying to run anaconda navigator 1.9.6 it takes forever to open.

Uninstalled and reinstalled.

Anaconda navigator should open within a minute or two.

[image: Image of Navigator Log Viewer]

```
{
    "time": "2019-04-17 08:22:09,705",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "module": "client_api",
    "method": "_get_api_info",
    "line": 606,
    "path": "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/client_api.py",
    "message": "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError('bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])')))"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so i have experienced the same problem and solved it by opening the navigator and going to

1. File
2. Preferences
3. uploading company root certificates to *SSL certificate path* input stored on a desktop directory

if you follow these steps it will open within 10 seconds ... if this is not setup and you have to go through a proxy every time you open navigator it overwrites any configs in your .condarc file (if you created that) ... learn more here=> https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html

if you can't get your companies root certifications in step #2 then you could try running this in the anaconda prompt ***when navigator is open***

```
conda config --set ssl_verify False
```

Comment: Thanks for that info! I doubt I will be able to get that certificate but I will look into it. We also use a proxy and the article below mentions white listing a couple urls but I am curious why our current version opens fine. I checked the .condarc file for one user and its just default no changes to it. https://support.anaconda.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2921276-using-anaconda-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy

Comment: you should be able to get the certs which will solve the problem however did you try running the conda config --set ssl_verify False via the anaconda prompt?